# After every "Refresh" duplicate record created in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using **JSP** as view and form submitting and **Servlet** as controller(Bussiness Logic) and **Hibernate** as DAO. whenever i create a new record then control redirected to listing page. and after every refresh duplicate data is created in DB.

I googled a lot but not got any sutisfactory solution.

Comment: You are posting form repeatedly by refreshing the page...hence the data is resent to the server and script executed.....it's worth checking the data received for validation

Comment: Why is data sent to server on refresh ? Don;t you use forms ? POST method ?

Comment: thanks. :) But, how to avoid this situation? I am using html method "post".

Comment: @AnkitKumar you need to redirect your page....you should check that duplicates records are not added.....it depends on your scenario and context...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show any code, but I can guess two problems:

1. You're using GET to post a form which creates something in the database. You should be using POST. If you did that, you would at least get a warning from the browser when refreshing the page
2. You don't redirect to the list page, but you forward to it. So when you refresh, the form is resubmitted and the object is recreated. Use the [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to solve this issue.

Comment: thanks Nizet :). Friend, I have googled and get some suggestions for using AJAX form submission. But I am new to java and never used AJAX before. SO should I go for that? or post-redirect-get is better solution?

Comment: Start simple. Use post-redirect-get. AJAX will come later.